# Add #if/#endif directives to DataContract attribute on CodeTypeDefinition of generated class

Tags: c#, datacontract, codedom

I'm working with an XSD -> C# class parser which generates classes for our data model, which is to be shared between a WPF client and a Silverlight web-based portion.

We are trying to augment the generated classes with `[DataContract]` attributes that should only be used when the SILVERLIGHT symbol is not defined, i.e.:

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT
[DataContract]
#endif
public class Class1 { /* ... */ }
```

How can I add this #if / #endif block to the `CodeTypeDefinition` of the **Class1**, or to the `CodeAttributeDeclaration` of **DataContract**?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're just getting started on this, you're better off using a T4 template.

Comment: Unfortunately, we aren't really "just getting started" -- this problem cropped up as we were preparing to share the data model to the Silverlight side.  The code is generated from XSD files which we do not own.  I hadn't heard of T4 templates before, so that might be something for future learning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've actually decided to do is add the `#if / #endif` tags through a Python script, after the code file is generated.  Robert's reply is functionally valid, but I just didn't feel right using two separate classes when one *should* be just fine.

Although it introduces another language into the data model generation, this seems like the cleanest way to get exactly what I want.  The script we are using is below.  It only needs to check for NonSerializable attributes (specifically, on PropertyChanged events) now because of a new way we structured the data contract.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from optparse import OptionParser
import shutil

# Use OptionParser to parse script arguments.
parser = OptionParser()

# Filename argument.
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", action="store", type="string", dest="filename", help="C# class file to parse", metavar="FILE.cs")

# Parse the arguments to the script.
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

# The two files to be used: the original and a backup copy.
filename = options.filename

# Read the contents of the file.
f = open( filename, 'r' )
csFile = f.read()
f.close()

# Add #if tags to the NonSerialized attributes.
csFile = csFile.replace('        [field: NonSerialized()]',
                    '        #if !SILVERLIGHT\r\n        [field: NonSerialized()]\r\n        #endif')

# Rewrite the file contents.
f = open( filename, 'r' )
f.write(csFile)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to get #if's emitted but you could instead generate two different versions of the class (one with the DataContract attribute, one without) and use a ConditionalAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) on them so the correct one is used for each environment

```
  CodeAttributeDeclaration declaration1 =
    new CodeAttributeDeclaration(
      "System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute",
      new CodeAttributeArgument(
        new CodePrimitiveExpression("SILVERLIGHT")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest adding the `[DataContract]` attribute on a generated class, since it will be overwritten when the class will be regenerated. If I were you, I would consider mapping your data model into DTOs (data transfer object) that will have the `[DataContract]` attribute using the method [Robert Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260366/add-if-endif-directives-to-datacontract-attribute-on-codetypedefinition-of-gene/7260593#7260593) explained.

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to help you map your model to your DTOs.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your suggestion because I'm trying to add the DataContract attribute __at__ generation time.  I haven't heard of DTO's before, I will try to look into those as well.